Will Triflic Acid Damage PTFE?
We recently received an ampule of trifluoromethanesulfonic acid (TFSA) for use in upcoming experiments in the lab. Once we open the ampule we'll need a bottle to store it in. We have amber glass vials with PTFE caps. But, I cannot find conclusive evidence online as to the impact of TFSA on PTFE (Teflon). Would the acid damage PTFE if the two are in physical contact for an extended amount of time?

Not really. CF3SO3H is quite gentle, afaik. You could even use glass. Fluorosulfuric on the other hand...

To be clear, "gentle" is a relative term for a superacid! PTFE and glass should be fine, but neat triflic acid damages most non-fluorinated polymers in seconds (e.g., do not syringe it with a disposable polypropylene syringe, and replace contaminated gloves immediately!) and it attacks many organics very aggressively.

What does triflic acid do to Teflon
Triflic acid which is a commercially available superacid behaves like most superacids but is a weaker one. This means a huge amount of fluorinated polymers - namely teflon in your example are resistant to the acid. This is due to the incredible strength of the C - F bond. Teflon in itself is so strong it can withstand the strongest possible superacids like fluoroantimonic acid.
Storing triflic acid
If you are wondering what is safest to store triflic acid, I would most strongly advise a teflon or any strong fluorinated polymer. The fluorinated polymer should be thick otherwise over time, corrosional damage would occur to container. It is also safe to store in thick HDPE bottles.   To answer your question about using glass vials, it is safe to store triflic acid in glass vials / bottles as factors afecting ability of acid to dissolve through glass are if it is a VERY strong superacid or any strongly fluorine donating compounds that will break S = O bonds in Silica to form Si - F bonds like hydrofluoric acid. Make sure you also use gloves - Thick nitrile rubber gloves offer good protection.
